# JavaScript + HTML: How to write a string literal to a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, html, file, io, fwrite

I am trying to program a recipe website in JavaScript.  The recipe editor is able to load in contents from a JSON file by creating HTML elements to store them.  I want it to be able to then construct a string literal from the data as it is changed by the user, and write it back to the JSON file.

The file's path is **"/JS_Scripts/Recipes/JSON/test.json"**

```
function writeToRecipeFile(filePath)
{
    let formData = new FormData();
    let recipeFileContents = 
    `{
        "image": "",
        "title": "${document.getElementById("titleInput").value}",
        "description": "${document.getElementById("descriptionInput").innerText}",
        "ingredients": [`

    //Add ingredients array
    for(i = 1; i <= ingredientCount; i++)
    {
        recipeFileContents = recipeFileContents + 
        `[
            "${document.getElementById("ingredientType"+i).value}",
            ${document.getElementById("ingredientAmount"+i).value},
            "${document.getElementById("ingredientMeasurement"+i)}"
        ]`
        if(i < ingredientCount)
        {
            recipeFileContents = recipeFileContents + 
            `,
            `;
        }
    }

    recipeFileContents += 
    `   ],
        "steps": [
            `;

    //Add all steps
    for(i = 1; i < stepCount; i++)
    {
        recipeFileContents +=
        `"${document.getElementById("stepInput"+i).innerText}",
        `
    }


    //Add info
    recipeFileContents +=
    `   ],
        "info": [   ${document.getElementById("prep-time-hr").value}, 
                    ${document.getElementById("prep-time-min").value}, 
                    ${document.getElementById("servings").value}, 
                    ${document.getElemenyById("serving-size").value}, 
                    "${document.getElementById("prep-time-hr").value}" ]`;

    


    // End of JSON contents.  Put a fork in it, it's done!
    recipeFileContents +=
    `   ]
    }   
    `

    //FIXME: This is where I need to write recipeFileContents to test.json

}
```

I tried using

```
const fs = require('fs');

        fs.writeFile(filepath, recipeFileContents, (err) => {
            if(err) throw err;
        })
```

but it said "require is not defined" in the console.

Comment: Why do you create the JSON yourself? Use `JSON.stringify`. You can't use CommonJS in a browser.

Comment: I think you need to back up and decide if this is a purely server-side application or if it's going to be a web application with a backend, or if it will live just in a web browser. I say this because your example code seems to be a mixture of server and web.

Comment: Or you're looking for: [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API)

Comment: @jabaa I am not sure how to add to the JSON object with for loops if I am not using a template literal.  I apologize for all this, I am learning this on the fly for a college project due soon.

Comment: Create a JavaScript object: `recipeFileContents = { image: "", ingredients: [] }`, push elements into it: `recipeFileContents.ingredients.push(document.getElementById("ingredientType"+i).value)`, and serialize it: `JSON.stringify(recipeFileContents)`.

Comment: It looks like your code produces invalid JSON. I didn't test it, but trailing commas aren't allowed in JSON. At one point you handle this case, but at another point you don't, and that's the reason why shouldn't build JSON from text snippets.

Comment: @jabaa thank you for the advice.  I just need to know, once I build the JSON, how do I write it to a file on the server?

Comment: Either, you send the data using a form or you send the data using AJAX. On the the server-side, you can use `node:fs` as CommonJS module or ES module.